# How to edit 404 content via wp editor?

Tags: page-template, 404-error, wp-editor

So I've got to edit my 404 page. Since my client's website has 5 languages, I'd like to let him edit and translate the 404 page by himself, with normal WordPress editor. Also, we're currently using Polylang as the localization plugin.

Is there a way to have the theme's `404.php` as a regular page?

I've tried to create a page and then assign it to the 404 template via template name, but it doesn't work, because it seems that `$post` is not available inside the template, so I cannot write contents.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way.

- Create a regular page for 404 content, say 'Page not found';
- In your 404.php file, get that page data and then write down your content or whatever...

For example:

```
$page = get_page_by_title("Page not found");  
if($page) echo apply_filters('the_content',$page->post_content);
```

Obviously, you can do a lot more...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid `Error 404` on your sites absolutely and unconditionally.

Second, you can use a text widget somewhere on the `404.php` page. Put the following code into the `functions.php` to register a sidebar to put the widget in:

```
<?php

function error_404_widget_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Error 404 widget',
        'id'            => 'error_404',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'error_404_widget_init' );
```

And add the following into `404.php` template file, in the place you like:

```
<?php
dynamic_sidebar( 'error_404' );
```

After that you'll be able to add the widget to the sidebar and specify a text for each language using Polylang's default functionality.

- See [Widgetizing Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

Comment: I tried before finding my own solution, but it seems there are problems with the theme customizer about widgets for 404. I think some bug. Anyway I think using the content of a custom page is far more a versatile way :)